# Why does the \foreach command in TikZ give wrong results for step size 0.1?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How come that in the code below, `\foreach` is unable to give me round numbers?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x in {0.1,0.2,...,0.9}\node at (0,{-2*\x}){\tiny\x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}`. I think it is a standard issue of representing floating point numbers in computers, especially when one is using something that was not intended to do mathematical computations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The more technical explanation is that your step size - the decimal number `0.1` - has no exact  binary representation. In binary it has the infinite representation `0.0001100110011...`, similar to `1/3 == 0.3333...` in decimal.

So if you represent `0.1` using a finite number of bits, there is always an error. And that is what you are seeing here. As percusse said, this error accumulates when `pgf` adds the inaccurate step value multiple times.

However this is not always the case: If you choose a step size that can be represented exactly in binary, such as `1/8` or `0.125` (`0.001` in binary), there is no error:

```
\foreach\x in {0,0.125,...,1}\node at (0,{-2*\x}){\tiny\x};
```

[image: Loop with step size 0.125]

You can reduce (but not eliminate) the error by using step size `1` and then scaling it down:

```
\foreach\x [evaluate=\x as \y using \x/10] in {1,2,...,9}\node at (0,{-2*\y}){\tiny\y};
```

[image: Loop with step size 1, divided by 10]

Comment: So, to have finite representation, it should be of type `1/2^n`?

Comment: @Sigur: Correct. Multiples of `1/2^n` (for `n < 16` I think) can be represented accurately. More precisely, any number which can be represented with 16 fractional bits should work, eg. multiples of 0.375, which is 0.011 in binary.

Answer (score 12):

It's because whenever you use the `...` notation, TikZ performs calculations such as what is the second number `0.2` and what is the first one; `0.1` so what is the step size...

Then it does `0.2-0.1` operation to obtain the step size and TeX precision contaminates this result. After that TikZ starts adding the contaminated `0.1` to `0.2` (not `0.1` because these are given). You get noisy `0.3,0.4,...` so on.

If you write down `0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9` explicitly in the list, you can see that there is no problem printing them properly because no arithmetic is performed on the numbers and they are used as is.