# Why this loop with "evaluate" does not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \name using \x*20] in{0,0.05,0.1,0.15,...,5} 
  \node(\name)[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\x cm]{};

\node at(1){test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get an error saying that there is no shape named "1". The loop works fine (if you add a "draw" option the 12-polygons show up) except for the evaluating part.

**edit:** I just discovered that 0.05*20 yields 1,00006 instead of 1, so it cannot find a node named 1. Why is that? How can I get 1 from 0,05*20?

Comment: Try `int(\x*20)` instead of `\x*20`...

Comment: or use a `[count=\xi]` instead. But for your own sake, avoid node names are just numbers.

Comment: Borrowing Fritz's idea from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197262/why-does-the-foreach-command-in-tikz-give-wrong-results-for-step-size-0-1 you could write: `\foreach \x [evaluate={\size=(0.01*\x)};] in {0,...,100} \node (\x) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=12,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\size cm,draw=black!\x] {};` so that you have the nodes named with (exact) integers and a (relatively) small error in the size.

Comment: I see here 3 comments that looks like solutions. Why so often I see in TeX.SX comments like this ? Even if a solution is one line, I think better is to put as solution for all future readers. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Kpym see [this discussion in meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments)

Comment: @jfbu thanks for the info. There are very interesting answers.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, the variable `\name` is the result of `\x*20`, a float expression. So, you get `0.0`, `1.00006`, ... ,`100.0`. So your polygonal nodes are named `0.0`, `1.00006`, ... ,`100.0`.

(*You can't use `.` in the name of a node: `(a.10)` points on anchor with angle `10` from center of the `a` node.*)

You may use `int(\x*20)` to round your float expression:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \name using int(\x*20)] in{0,0.05,0.1,0.15,...,5} 
  \node(\name)[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=12,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\x cm]{};

\node at(1){test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```